# Astropy quantity in-place conversion

Tags: astropy

Is there a way to convert an astropy quantity to another set of units "in-place"? The `to` method always returns a copy so that's not so useful. Something like:

```
import astropy.units as u
data = [1, 2, 3]*u.g
data.convert_to('kg')
```

Both `Pint` and `yt.units` have in-place conversions:

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
u = UnitRegistry()
data = [1, 2, 3]*u.g
data.ito('kg')
```

and

```
from yt.units import g
data = [1, 2, 3]*g
data.convert_to_units('kg')
```

A cursory glance at the astropy docs and source code indicates that the answer is "no" but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do it at the moment. Given your example:

```
>>> import astropy.units as u
>>> data = [1, 2, 3] * u.g
>>> data
<Quantity [1., 2., 3.] g>
```

You can do this:

```
>>> data.value * u.kg
<Quantity [1., 2., 3.] kg>
```

Or this:

```
>>> data * u.kg / data.unit
<Quantity [1., 2., 3.] kg>
```

Or this:

```
>>> data._unit = u.kg
>>> data
<Quantity [1., 2., 3.] kg>
```

None of these ways copy the Numpy array, so are OK performance-wise for many applications.

I don't think there is a method available so that setting `data._unit` becomes possible without reaching for the private data member. This was discussed a bit (in the context of Column and Quantity objects) [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/6098#issuecomment-302530555) and I think the conclusion was that a `set_unit` method would be a useful addition, but it hasn't been implemented yet. So you could open an issue with that feature request [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues).